# Spring repository findBy join table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following models

**GameModel**

```java
// ...

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinTable(
    name = "game_genre",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "game_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id") } )
private List<GenreModel> genres;

// ...
```

**GenreModel**

```java
// ...

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres")
private List<GameModel> games;

// ...
```

Also, I have repositories for them.
How can I get all the games that belong to *(for example)* **genre** with id **1**? In the **GameModel**, I have no genres column, so I can not do it in the **GameRepository** using findByGenresContaining.

Comment: You can use findByGenresId(int id) in your repository

Comment: @billalGHILAS thank you, it works but in my case it is **public List<GameModel> findByGenresIdIn(List<Integer> id);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@billalGHILAS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12436427/billal-ghilas)
It works like this:

```java
// find games that belong to one genre
public List<GameModel> findByGenresId(int id);

// find games that belong to list of genres
public List<GameModel> findByGenresIdIn(List<Integer> id);
```